# Notes cannot create automation object

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have created an agent iin which I call a dll file so that I can get data from another system eventually..
When I manually run this agent then the call to the dll file works and I get data from it.

When I call this agent from a browser then I get:

```
Error Description : Cannot create automation object
```

The security of the agent is on 3.Allow restricted operations with full administration rights.

Any idea why I get Cannot create automation object when running agent from browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start the agent from browser then the agent runs on Domino **server**.

So, you need to install automation object's software on this server.

When you manually run the agent then the code is executed on your client. This works because you installed the software necessary for creating the automation object on your client.

Comment: @KnutHermann It is installed on the server. But domino server is 64 bit and dll is 32 bit maybe this could be the problem?

Comment: Yes, this is the issue.

Comment: @KnutHermann I also tried to make a 2nd agent and try to call the first agent by using .run this also does not work.. any idea to create a workaround for this??

Comment: Not really. Install the 64bit version of your software (I guess you don't have it) *or* install 32bit version of Domino (probably you don't want to) *or* execute agent on client as "scheduled local agent".

Comment: Or write a 32 bit service that calls the DLL, install the service on the Domino server, and talk to the service from your agent. Easier said than done, though.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same error but in my case everything was working properly until we restored a backup of Windows. The issue was caused because Office had to be reactivated again.

Sometimes this happens too because a corruption of the Word document, so you have to rebuild it.

I hope this could be helpful in future to other people